# Facebook Android SDK 3.0 calls just show a white screen

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, apk, android-facebook

I have a lot of issues with the Facebook Android SDK 3.0 — a lot. Here's one which is particularly annoying: I have added the Facebook project to my workspace and linked it to my Android application. Now when I export my application (by right clicking on the project in Eclipse, selecting the *Android Tools* option and then clicking *Export Signed Application Package*), my signed application package exports okay. I notice however that around 50% of the time I export my APK, when I then make any Facebook SDK request using this APK (like opening a session or requesting additional permissions or anything of the like), I just get a white screen showing a progress bar which hangs indefinitely, as follows...

[image]

It hangs there until I press the device's <kbd>Back</kbd> button, at which point I get a `SessionState.CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED` session callback. Basically, it builds badly on almost every other export. Is anyone else experiencing this or know how I can stop this from happening? It's very very time-consuming having to build two or three times until I get a good APK. I am refreshing the projects in my workspace and doing a *Project -> Clean -> Clean all projects* every time and even that doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done the last few times I've had to export my signed application package is to go to my project's properties, open the Android option, remove the Facebook library reference and then re-add it. I've had five consecutive good exports doing this so I'm guessing this does the trick!

Comment: i'm facing the same problem can you tell me how you solve it please cause i'm stuck at this bug for 10 days ..thanks